# Proving $2\cot⁡4x = \cot⁡2x - \tan⁡2x$

Tags: trigonometry

How to prove the trigonometry equation is an identity?

$$2\cot⁡4x = \cot⁡2x - \tan⁡2x$$

Thank you in advance.

Thank you for the comments and hints. I got an answer after many tries. ;)
Below is my answer. Thank you.

$2cot4x = cot2x - tan2x$

$2\frac{1}{tan 4x} = cot2x - tan2x$

$2\frac{1}{\frac{2 tan 2x}{1 - tan^2 2x}} = cot2x - tan2x$

$2\frac{1 - tan^2 2x}{2 tan 2x} = cot2x - tan2x$

$\frac{1}{tan 2x} -  \frac{tan^2 2x}{tan 2x} = cot2x - tan2x$

$cot2x - tan2x = cot2x - tan2x$

Comment: I solved your problem. If you want to see my solution, show please your attempts.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**:

Express both sides with the $\tan$ function and use the duplication formula for the tangent:
$$\tan2\theta=\frac{2\tan \theta}{1-\tan^2\theta}.$$

Comment: Thank you for the hints. :)

Answer (score 1):

Thank you for the comments and hints. I got an answer after many tries. ;)
Below is my answer.

$$\begin{align}
2\cot4x = \cot2x - \tan2x \\ 
2\cdot\frac{1}{\tan 4x} = \cot2x - \tan2x\\
2\cdot\frac{1}{\frac{2 \tan 2x}{1 - \tan^2 2x}} = \cot2x - \tan2x\\
2\cdot\frac{1 - \tan^2 2x}{2 \tan 2x} = \cot2x - \tan2x\\
\frac{1}{\tan 2x} -  \frac{\tan^2 2x}{tan 2x} = \cot2x - \tan2x\\
\cot2x - \tan2x = \cot2x - \tan2x\end{align}$$

Comment: Thank you for the comments and suggestion. I have updated the answer. :)

Answer (score 0):

Another way:

We need to prove that $$\cot4x+\tan2x+\cot4x-\cot2x=0$$ or
$$\frac{\cos2x}{\sin4x\cos2x}-\frac{\sin2x}{\sin4x\sin2x}=0,$$ which is obvious in the domain.

Answer (score 0):

$$
\cot\alpha-\tan\alpha=\frac{\cos^2\alpha-\sin^2\alpha}{\sin\alpha\cos\alpha}=\frac{\cos2\alpha}{\frac{1}{2}\sin2\alpha}
$$